# VBScript throw exception when the receiving object is C# COM object and the function has interface as parameter

Tags: c#, com, vbscript

Here is my VBScript code

```
Set object= CreateObject("Demo. Object")
Set service= CreateObject("Demo.ManageServer ")
service.SetObject object
```

I get the following  message:

> **Error**: Invalid procedure call or
>   argument: ‘Service.SetObject’ Code:
>   800A005

Demo.Service is  C# COM object

```
[ProgId("Demo.ManageServer")]
[Guid("A4F0A0F0-9C0C-4C71-AD58-A36F750D92FE")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyServer :IMyServer
{
    public void SetObject (IMyObject obj) { … }     
}
```

The interface:

```
[TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FDual | TypeLibTypeFlags.FNonExtensible | TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]
[Guid("B3ACBCAD-5ED3-4113-B9D2-FC67FA49012B")]
public interface IMyServer
{
     [DispId(1)]
     void SetObject (IMyObject obj);
}
```

NOTE:

1)    When I sent ‘Nothing’ as parameter to the function it works ok

2)    When I change the interface of the function to receive object, it also work again.

Do you know why using explicit Type in the function signature, VBScript throws exception?

I already tried it and it does not work.
In addition, 
If the receiver is C++ COM object I have no problem to send both Manage and Unmanaged Objects
If the receiver  is C# COM object I can pass a manage object only if I use parenthesis

manageServer.PrintType (nativeObject)
Without the parenthesis I receive the same exception 
But in case I tries to send into a unmanaged code an unmanaged object nothing help

Comment: Please show the definition of `IMyObject` and at least the outline of your `Demo.Object` class. Also, do you really have a space in there ("Demo. Object")?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Object, the CLR will accept the IDispatch reference which VBS is passing.
When you then cast it to your interface type, the CLR will use the usual QueryInterface approach.

You may have luck when you mark the parameter as such:

```
 [DispId(1)]
 void SetObject ([UnmanagedType.Interface]IMyObject obj);
```

This should tell the CLR that it will receive something compatible to IUnknown and that it should try to use QueryInterface to cast it to your interface type.

Comment: I already tried it and it does not work.
In addition, 
If the receiver is C++ COM object I have no problem to send both Manage and Unmanaged Objects
If the receiver  is C# COM object I can pass a manage object only if I use parenthesis 



manageServer.PrintType (nativeObject)
Without the parenthesis I receive the same exception 
But in case I tries to send into a unmanaged code an unmanaged object nothing help